# Regex to get html value based on unique class

Tags: regex, perl

I'm using regex to parse a website in perl.
The content of the site look like this:

```
(much text) </div> <div class="euroPrice"> <span>1.23</span> 
(much text) </div> <div class="euroPrice"> <span>2.34</span> (much text)
```

with (much text) beeing standard html. I would like to get the numbers 1.23 and 2.34, but I have to use regex. 
Any hints?

I tried something like this:

```
class="euroPrice"> <span>([\d\.]+)
```

But that only gave me the first one.

Comment: Ugh. Just... [don't](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/82262).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better get your spans first (via an xpath) and get the span numbers with @Tims's regex. An xpath to get your spans would be:

```
("//div[@class='euroPrice']/span")
```

Comment: Whilst I agree, I'm not sure which modules I'd be XPathify HTML. (My XML parsers tend to get upset by some of the HTMLisms)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the text for the website and apply the following code for each line:

```
$line = "(much text) </div> <div class="euroPrice"> <span>1.23</span>";
if ($line =~ /<div class="euroPrice"> <span>(\d+\.\d+)<\/span>/) {
    print "first a number: $1 in current line\n";
}
```

This solution assumes that there will be at most one match per line.

You can explore the regular expression here:

[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/mF4tO1/1)